# How to add numbers in a string in bartender label vb scripting

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript, bartender

Hi how can i implement the below logic in bartender vb scripting?

`X18 VL40197366` = 33+1+8+38+31+21+4+0+1+9+7+3+6+6=168 
�where `X=33`, `" "=38`, `V=31, L=21`.

Now the above result is stored to a variable called "temp1"
where temp1 contains now=168;
`temp1=168``

My codes goes below. I know my code is not complete, please correct me if i am wrong

```
 Dim A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
 A = 10
 B=11
 C=12
 D=13
 E=14
 F=15
 G=16
 H=17
 I=18
 J=19
 K=20
 L=21
 M=22
 N=23
 O=24
 P=25
 Q=26
 R=27
 S=28
 T=29
 U=30
 V=31
 W=32
 X=33
 Y=34
 Z=35
 'Here i don't know how to declare the values for special characters and number
 'I need to assign, if my final result is 0,...to 9, i need 0 to 9 as result.
 'In addition to that, if my final result is 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, I need to show the corresponding symbols - . "" $ / + %

 Dim temp1,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6, temp7, temp8
float temp2

temp4 = Format.Objects("Text 1").Value 'Here i input first three characters depending on user input, ex:X18
'how can i give a check option here to add the above text , for ex, i need the result called 33+1+8 to be stored
 'I have syntax called IIF(ConditionalExpr, ExprIfTrue, ExprIfFalse)

temp5= Format.Objects("Text 2").Value 'Here i input second three characters depending on user inputer, this is the characters after the space ex:VL4
  'same here too,

temp6= Format.Objects("Text 3").Value 'Here i input third 7 characters depending on user inputer, ex:0197366
  'same here too,

temp7 = 38 'this variable is for the space always this is constant 

'temp1=temp4+temp7+temp5+temp6'but this code is giving me result called X1838VL40197366, which is incorrect. I need to be like shown as below
temp1= "" 'should hold the addition of all above for ex: 33+1+8+38+31+21+4+0+1+9+7+3+6+6=168
```

How to implement this!

thanks in advance

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: But please this is my first time, sorry about that, please pardon me

Comment: Sure, you should edit your question so that it is clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, I clearly don't understand what you're trying to do.**

But, In your case you should use [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) class instead of declaring individual variables.

```
Dim dicResult as new Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
Dim arrSymballs() As String = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"} ''You can add more
Dim iValue As Decimal  = 10
For i As Integer = 0 To arrSymballs.Length-1
    dicResult.Add(arrSymballs(i), iValue)
    iValue += 1
Next

''Function to get string from result
''I don't know how the result you will get the following logic is for  "10,11,12,13,14,15"
Private Function getResultString(_result As String) As Decimal
    Dim dNumResult As Decimal
    For Each c As String in _result.Split(",")
        dNumResult += dicResult(c)
    Next
    Return dNumResult
End Function
```

Comment: Shell thanks, but how to give the values for the declared variables??

Comment: The problem is in bartender programmer i cannot give like above, i am getting error as `OnAutoSelectedEvent (Line 3): Dim dicResult as new Dictionary(Of String, Decimal): Expected end of statement`

Comment: can you come to team viewer please...??

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring your variable as numeric types.  The compiler is guessing that you want them to be strings because `Format` returns a string. You will have to cast the string values into numeric values.

> Integer.Parse(text)

```
temp6 = Integer.Parse(temp5) + x
```

Consider using arrays when you have a large number of variables.

```
Dim iValues As Integer() = New Integer() {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}
```

> temp6 = Integer.Parse(temp5) + iValues(24)

Comment: The problem is in bartender programmer i cannot give like above, i am getting error as `OnAutoSelectedEvent (Line 2): Dim iValues As Integer() = New Integer() {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}: Expected end of statement`